# NextJs API endpoint returning response object without 'message' or 'body'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik

I have a NextJs app where

1. Users could fill in some input fields and submit the form (Formik Form).
2. Form submission is handled by the API route to do some calculations (I can do this on the client side but it's required to do it on the server side in this case)

Everything is working fine except for the response object that is returned by the API endpoint to the client

/pages/api/calculation.js

```
const handler = (req, res) => {
  // deny the request if not post method
  req.method !== 'POST' &&
    res.status('403').json({
      status: 403,
      message: 'Forbidden',
    });

  // all the logic goes here

  // return the response
  // also tried a few others like (res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello from Next.js!' });
  return res.send({ status: 200, message: 'Hello from Next.js!' });
};

export default handler;
```

/pages/index.jsx

```
Inside Formik's onSubmit prop

fetch('/api/mbti/result', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(values),
}).then((res) => {
   console.log(res);

   if (res.status === 200) {
      resetForm(); // reset form
   }
});
```

This is the response object

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/calculation"
```

On the client side, I would like to get access to the 'message' inside the body from the response object that is returned by the API. Currently, the body inside the response object is only `(...)` as you could see above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using fetch, you'll want to convert the [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) body to [json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json). By default, the Response body is a [Readable Stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body).

You can use Promise thenables:

```js
fetch('/api/mbti/result', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(values),
}).then(res => {
  if (!res.ok) {
    res.text().then(err => throw new Error(err));
  }

  return res.json();
}).then(data => {
  console.log('API response data', data);

  resetForm(); // reset form
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Or, I'd recommend that you use async/await because it's a bit cleaner:

```js
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async values => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('/api/mbti/result', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
    });
    
    if (!res.ok) {
      const error = await res.text();
      throw new Error(error);
    }
    
    const data = await res.json();
    
    console.log("API response data", data);

    resetForm();
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

On a related note, you have a bug in your API endpoint where it'll try to send headers after they've already been sent:

```js
const handler = (req, res) => {
  // deny the request if not post method

  // if you don't return here, then it'll continue down the call stack and try to send a valid response as well
  if(req.method !== 'POST')
    return res.status('403').json({
      status: 403,
      message: 'Forbidden',
    });


  // return the valid response
  return res.send({ status: 200, message: 'Hello from Next.js!' });
};

export default handler;
```

Comment: please have a look at this, I've tried virtually different things ---------> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77214289/warning-only-plain-objects-can-be-passed-from-server-components-to-client-compo