# Warning: only plain objects can be passed from server components to client components next js 13

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, next.js13

I'm making a request from my server component to the client component. Basically I can see the values in JSON format on the server components but when I do a return, It shows a warning on the server side then a pre-rendered html page on the client side..

Here's my client's component-------------->

```js
  // addToCartHandler
  const addToCartHandler = async () => {
    if (!size) {
      setError("Please Select a size");
      return;
    }
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `/api/product/${product._id}?style=${product.style}&size=${dsize}`
    )
    
    console.log("object_dataToJson", data);
    if (qty > data.quantity) {
      setError(
        "The Quantity you have choosed is more than in stock. Try and lower the Qty"
      );
    } else if (data.quantity  < 1) {
      setError("This Product is out of stock.");
      return;
    } else {
      let _uid = `${data._id}_${product.style}_${dsize}`;
      console.log("object_uid", _uid);
      let exist = cart.cartItems.find((p) => p._uid === _uid);
      if (exist) {
        let newCart = cart.cartItems.map((p) => {
          if (p._uid == exist._uid) {
            return { ...p, qty: qty };
          }
          return p;
        });
        dispatch(updateCart(newCart));
      } else {
        dispatch(
          addToCart({
            ...data,
            qty,
            size: data.size,
            _uid,
          })
        );
      }
    }
  };
  // addToCartHandler
```

Here's the api page handler on the server side -------------------->

```js
import db from "../../../../utils/db";
import Product from "../../../../models/Product";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";


export default async function ProductDetailspage({params, searchParams}){
  db.connectDb();
  const id = params.id;
  const size = searchParams.size;
  const style = searchParams.style;
  const product = await Product.findById(id).lean();
  let discount = product.subProducts[style].discount;
  let priceBefore = product.subProducts[style].sizes[size].price;
  let price = discount ? priceBefore - priceBefore / discount : priceBefore;
  db.disconnectDb();

  const productDetails = ({
    _id: product._id,
    style: Number(style),
    name: product.name,
    description: product.description,
    slug: product.slug,
    sku: product.subProducts[style].sku,
    brand: product.brand,
    category: product.category,
    subCategories: product.subCategories,
    shipping: product.shipping,
    images: product.subProducts[style].images,
    color: product.subProducts[style].color,
    size: product.subProducts[style].sizes[size].size,
    price,
    priceBefore,
    quantity: product.subProducts[style].sizes[size].qty,
  })

  const dataJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(productDetails));
  console.log(dataJson);
  
  return new NextResponse({dataJson});

}
```

I've converted the object to a JSON, when I clg it returns a json[image]

But on return, It still gives the warning and I can't see the data like it appears on my clg on the terminal(server), please what's happening-------->